# ¿Cómo actualizar un valor mediante una condición?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo una tabla en formato *MySQL* donde tengo *como 20 filas*, entre todas esas columnas hay una que se llama `open` el cual vale *1*, y tengo otra tabla `dirección` con los mismos valores el cual también una columna `open` pero esta vale cero.

Entonces lo que yo quiero hacer es que si en la tabla formato `open=1` en la tabla dirección automáticamente se guarde el mismo valor *1*, solo ese valor, sé que se puede usar una llave foránea, pero lo que yo quiero es que automáticamente lo guarde.

Código:

```
if ($row['open'] == 1) {
    echo '<td><a style="color: #6495ED;" hef="?msg='.$id.'">'.$open.'</td>';
}
else if($row['open'] == 1){
    $id = $_GET['msg'];
    // process form
    $update = mysql_query("UPDATE direccion2 SET open ='2' WHERE id='$id'");
    $msg = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM direccion2 WHERE id = '$id'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($msg);
    exit();
}
else{
    echo '<td><a href="?msg='.$id.'">'.$open.'</td>';
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola! tienes muchas preguntas abiertas que no has aceptado. Ninguna de las respuestas te sirvio?

Comment: Y lo quieres hacer en el codigo o quieres crear un trigger?

Comment: `if ($row['open'] == 1) {
   ...
}
else if($row['open'] == 1){` No va a entrar por la condición del elseif en la vida, observa, es la misma condición que pone en el if, si $row['open'] == 1 siempre va a entrar por el if.

Comment: gracias o checare.